# System.ArgumentException when trying to install Nuget Package Manager extension

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, nuget-package

I've been trying to install Nuget Package Manager in Visual Studio 2012, but i'm getting System.ArgumentException when installing.
Watch log.

```
07/03/2016 9:22:33 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
07/03/2016 9:22:33 - -------------------------------------------
07/03/2016 9:22:33 - Initializing Install...
07/03/2016 9:22:34 - Detalles de la extensión...
07/03/2016 9:22:34 -    Identifier      : NuPackToolsVsix.Microsoft.67e54e40-0ae3-42c5-a949-fddf5739e7a5
07/03/2016 9:22:34 -    Name            : NuGet Package Manager
07/03/2016 9:22:34 -    Author          : Microsoft Corporation
07/03/2016 9:22:34 -    Version         : 2.8.60318.667
07/03/2016 9:22:34 -    Description     : A collection of tools to automate the process of downloading, installing, upgrading, configuring, and removing packages from a VS Project.
07/03/2016 9:22:34 -    Locale          : en-US
07/03/2016 9:22:34 -    MoreInfoURL     : http://nuget.codeplex.com/documentation
07/03/2016 9:22:34 -    InstalledByMSI  : False
07/03/2016 9:22:34 -    SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.0,4.5]
07/03/2016 9:22:34 - 
07/03/2016 9:22:34 -    SignedBy        : Microsoft Corporation
07/03/2016 9:22:34 -    Certificate Info : [Subject]
  CN=Microsoft Corporation, OU=MOPR, OU=OPC, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US

[Issuer]
  CN=Microsoft Code Signing PCA, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US

[Serial Number]
  [Hide]

[Not Before]
  22/04/2014 19:39:04

[Not After]
  22/07/2015 19:39:04

[Thumbprint]
  9DD77A79F7124D8DB128A526833CF3760FCB7794

07/03/2016 9:22:34 -    Productos admitidos : 
07/03/2016 9:22:34 -        Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
07/03/2016 9:22:34 -            Version : [10.0]
07/03/2016 9:22:34 -        Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
07/03/2016 9:22:34 -            Version : [11.0]
07/03/2016 9:22:34 -        Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntegratedShell
07/03/2016 9:22:34 -            Version : [10.0]
07/03/2016 9:22:34 -        Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntegratedShell
07/03/2016 9:22:34 -            Version : [11.0]
07/03/2016 9:22:34 -        Microsoft.VisualStudio.VWDExpress
07/03/2016 9:22:34 -            Version : [10.0]
07/03/2016 9:22:34 -        Microsoft.VisualStudio.VWDExpress
07/03/2016 9:22:34 -            Version : [11.0]
07/03/2016 9:22:34 -        Microsoft.VisualStudio.VPDExpress
07/03/2016 9:22:34 -            Version : [11.0]
07/03/2016 9:22:34 -        Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSWinExpress
07/03/2016 9:22:34 -            Version : [11.0]
07/03/2016 9:22:34 -        Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSWinDesktopExpress
07/03/2016 9:22:34 -            Version : [11.0]
07/03/2016 9:22:34 - 
07/03/2016 9:22:34 -    Referencias     : 
07/03/2016 9:22:34 - 
07/03/2016 9:22:42 - System.ArgumentException: El valor no está dentro del intervalo esperado.
   en System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Settings.ExternalSettingsManager.GetScopePaths(String applicationPath, String suffixOrName, String vsVersion, Boolean isLogged, Boolean isForIsolatedApplication)
   en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Settings.ExternalSettingsManager.CreateForApplication(String applicationPath)
   en VSIXInstaller.App.GetExtensionManager(SupportedVSSKU sku)
   en VSIXInstaller.App.GetExtensionManagerForApplicableSKU(SupportedVSSKU supportedSKU, IInstallableExtension installableExtension, List`1 applicableSKUs)
   en VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
   en System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   en System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

I cannot figure out which is the item out of bounds. I can install the packages without nuget but is much more tiring, do it one by one.
Anyone with this exception? [OS Windows 7 pro [34bits]]

Comment: Package Manager should be installed by default since VS2010. Are you sure you need this? Have you checked under the Menu Tools if its there?

Comment: It's not essential but nuget tools is much more confortable for VS plugins installation